# SQL - Need a way around multiple WHERE restraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have an aggregate function in my WHERE statement along with other more normal WHERE restraints. If I use all AND statements to tie the WHERE statement together, then the query checks out fine.

However, I need to use an OR statement to have the proper data. When I try to run the query with the OR statement, I receive a **"Divide by Zero"**
 error. It is occurring despite one of my restraints is that the ExampleQuantity cannot equal 0.

How should I work around this to where I can both use the OR statement, and not have a divide by zero error? I'm sure that there is an easy solution to this, I just cannot see it.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ExampleCode1 BETWEEEN 1 AND 10 
  AND ExampleNo IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
  **AND/OR** ExampleQuantity =! 0 
  AND ExamplePrice/ExampleQuantity = ExampleAmount
```

Comment: Remember it's not a procedural language thus the Engine can decide the "order of execution" and even try to execute something in parallel. In this case you can change the test to **ExamplePrice = ExampleAmount * ExampleQuantity**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `jean` suggests, simply rewriting the division as a multiplication avoids dividing by zero.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ExampleCode1 BETWEEEN 1 AND 10 
AND ExampleNo IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
OR  ExamplePrice * ExampleQuantity = ExampleAmount
```

I think your test may be wrong, usually *price* means *price per unit* and *amount* represents *total price*

Comment: Price, Quantity and Amount lazy placeholder for the actual values.  I believe that rewrite will work, however, I am unable to test it right now. I don't know why I didn't think of that to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM table1
   WHERE ExampleCode1 BETWEEEN 1 AND 10 
   AND ExampleNo IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
   AND ExampleQuantity =! 0 
) tab_tmp
WHERE AND ExamplePrice/ExampleQuantity = ExampleAmount;
```